# Iceland Transit Visa for Canadian Residence ( Indian Passport Holder)

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas

I am an Indian Citizen and Canadian PR holder. Want to book the flight from YYZ ( wow airline) have a route through Iceland (6.55 hours hold) to New-Delhi. Do I require Iceland Visa or Transit Visa?

My outward flight is:

> Fri, Jan 11, 2019 Toronto (YYZ) 06:00PM New Delhi (DEL) 03:15 AM + 2
>   day
>
> Flight 1: | 5h 45m | WW214 | Operated by: WOW air Layover: 6h 55m
>   | Reykjavik (KEF)
>
> Flight 2: | 10h 5m | WW322 | Operated by: WOW air

And return flight is:

> Wed, Jan 30, 2019 New Delhi (DEL) 07:00 AMToronto (YYZ) 05:00 PM
>
> Flight 1: | 11h 50m | WW323 | Operated by: WOW air Layover: 2h 10m |
>   Reykjavik (KEF)
>
> Flight 2: | 6h 30m | WW213 | Operated by: WOW air

Comment: Under rule #5 in the accepted answer there, your Canadian residence permit allows you to transit without visa through any Schengen country (assuming you can make the transit without needing to leave the secure area).